# BIM model host and render

Tags: javascript, java, web, ifc, bim

I am planning to set up server to parse and host BIM models and access the specific models form the client.

Expectation:
        I should be able to host many BIM models (100s), preferably IFC, and there are many clients whos accessing this models from browser.

I have tested  BIM server and Bimsurfer, in my understanding BIMserver is for collaborative development where about 10 users co-working on project;
        based on the resource spec I doubt its performance on large number of concurrent users;
        Other options are  are Autodesk Forge, xBIM, BIMWebServer, they looked similar and there is less scope for customization.
        What kind of BIM platform,tools you recommend me for above use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although IfcOpenShell is a perfect development for its own purpose, developing a conversion and rendering pipeline with ThreeJS can be a bad experience. For such a platform you described, you would need a high capacity server to host, upload, process and render the files. Also keep in your mind, unless you modify the source code of IfcOpenShell your exported models can have higher sizes (in MB) than the original ifc file. Rendering those files in cloud will be challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were no responses, I'll share my findings so far:
Option1 :
Use Openshellconvert in combination with Front end rendering like Threejs, Openshell converter mainly helps to get data info from IFC files and translate them to desired rendering formats like collada or obj etc
Opetion2 :
Go for proprietary solution like Forge where you have wide range of supported file formats, Resfull APIs to query BIM properties it has readily available viewer which can be embedded in your client